# Transaction rollback function not work in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

when i run this code data insert in 3 tables successfully and commit when in give the error in in **3rd table insert query** then data insert in 1st and 2nd table and not in 3rd table and also not **RollBack** function work properly. I want do when 3rd table query not work then 1st and 2nd table insert data will remove and delete.

```
    $this->db->trans_start(TRUE);

    // 1st table insert query
    $this->db->insert('users',$userInfo);
    $userId = $this->db->insert_id();

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT `roleId` FROM `role` WHERE roleName='Clint';");
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
    { $roleId = $row['roleId']; }

    $user_role = array( 'user_id' => $userId, 'role_id' => $roleId );
    // 2nd table insert query
    $this->db->insert('user_role', $user_role);

    $city_id += [ "projectInfo" => $userId ];
    // 3rd table insert query
    $this->db->insert('project', $projectInfo);

    $this->db->trans_complete();
    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE )
    {
            echo "Flase";
            $this->db->trans_rollback();
    }
    else
    {
            echo "True";
            $this->db->trans_rollback();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are manually rolling back transactions! In this case, you should use

$this->db->trans_begin();  NOT  $this->db->trans_start();

CI automatically rolls back transactions, you dont need do it manually.
If you use $this->db->trans_start, you dont need $this->db->trans_rollback().

Comment out $this->db->trans_rollback(), or leave those and use $this->db->trans_begin(), then check results.

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html

Good luck!